# JTree Conundrum: Tree vs. Branch by Vector Extension

Tags: java, swing, nodes, jtree, extends

It seems that when I add a custom object to a JTree, the tree will recognize it as a branch if it extends Vector, but as a leaf when it does not. I'm designing a custom renderer to allow check boxes in all of my cells (both branches and trees). This would not be hard except that I want to be able to nest indefinitely.

This really isn't a code question, but more of a logic question. Basically the behavior I am trying to get it the same class with an optional Vector extension. I know that is not possible but that's the behavior that will be required to do this.

Here is my current JTree:

[image: JTree current.]

and here is the code that got me to that point.

Method in the GUI to produce JTree:

```
public void start() {
    CheckBoxLeaf node = new CheckBoxLeaf("1 Leaf");
    CheckBoxLeaf node2 = new CheckBoxLeaf("2 Leaf");

    CheckBoxLeaf node3 = new CheckBoxLeaf("Red Leaf");
    CheckBoxLeaf node4 = new CheckBoxLeaf("Blue Leaf");

    CheckBoxBranch parent = new CheckBoxBranch("Dr. ", new CheckBoxLeaf[]{node, node2});
    CheckBoxBranch parent2 = new CheckBoxBranch("Seuss", new CheckBoxLeaf[]{node3, node4});

    JTree tree = new JTree(new CheckBoxBranch[]{parent, parent2});
    tree.setCellRenderer(new custom.jtree.TreeCellRenderer());

    infoScroll = new JScrollPane(tree);
}
```

Leaf class:

```
public class CheckBoxLeaf {

    private final String text;

    public CheckBoxLeaf(String name) {
        text = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Branch class:

```
public class CheckBoxBranch extends Vector {

    private final String text;

    public CheckBoxBranch(String name, CheckBoxLeaf[] subNodes) {
        text = name;
        addAll(Arrays.asList(subNodes));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

My renderer class really isn't important at the moment as it does nothing except force all cells to have JCheckBoxes.

This code in it's current state will just allow leafs to be nested into branches. It does not allow for branches to be nested within other branches which is what I'm attempting to do.

If anyone can offer up some help for me it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Wrap your data in a TreeNode of some kind and make sure isLeaf returns the current value for the type of data you are representing

Comment: Thanks that helped me a lot actually. Now, for some reason I am getting drop-down arrows on leaves and when I click them they disappear. Any help?

Comment: That will come down to your how you are rendering the nodes

Comment: Okay thanks, I will look into it.

Comment: Renderer seems to be ignoring isLeaf()

Comment: What renderer are you using?  Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

to avoid showing arrows on leaf nodes, you can override following method in your tree model as shown below:

```
@Override
public boolean isLeaf(Object node){
    return node instanceof CheckBoxLeaf;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My overall solution to this problem was just to use the standard DafaultMutableTreeNode object and add a custom renderer